# The timer in javascript showing error, How can I fix That?

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a timer  which is supposed to take the value  equal to input value given by user for  no.of question  to set timer . I.e for example if user enters no.of questions = 5 (it can be any value) then after submiting the form the timer for 5 minutes shoud starts running and after 5 min gets over it should redirect to form .
but It is showing NaN-NaN  instead of time , Why is this happening 
I have attached screenshot of output I am getting [image: in this pic the Nan-NaN is displaying instead of showing time]

This is my javascript code

```
 var seconds = "<?php echo $num_questions * 60; ?>";//setting time equal to no. of questions given by user 
              function secondPassed() 
                {
                   var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60),
                    remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
                      if (remainingSeconds < 10) 
                        {
                           remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
                        }
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
                      if (seconds == 0) 
                         {
                           clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
                           window.location.href;
                         } 
                    else
                         {
                          seconds--;
                         }
               }
                  var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

This is the code where I am  echoing the timer

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['play']))
        { ?>
       <time id="countdown"><?php
        echo $num_questions; ?></time> <?php } ?>
```

here Play is my submit button and value of $num_questions will be inpt given by user.
How can I fix It?

Comment: `var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000)` here first argument should be method name without quotes as `var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000)`

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion , now it is neither shwing Nan-Nan ,  nor the timer is set it is just shwing the value I have entered in form input fieild , i.e I gave input of 4 no of questions and its showing just 4 not the timer countdown.....  How is that happening?

Comment: Can you log and check the value by which `var seconds` is initialised?

Comment: Its showing error in   var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);   and   in the header where I have included my jquery soource file

Comment: Do I need to chnage the source file of Jquery?

Comment: @ Nishant Saini  its still not wrking even after I  replace jquery source file in header,  what should I do ?

Comment: check here its working: https://jsfiddle.net/jmdxnk8L/

Comment: @ Nishant Saini   yes its working , solution is correct but its just taking the value of $num_questions and not setting count down  , Do you have any idea what will be the reason?

Comment: Please update the code in question with any correction you have made so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184554/discussion-between-nishant-saini-and-user10625430).

Comment: @ Nishant Saini  hey I have update dthe code in the chat discussion forum can you check it ?

Comment: @ Nishant Sain   its still showing  0 in alert window

Comment: @ Nishant Sain hey sorry to bother you again but he timer is still not working its showing  0 in alert box can you check out the chat forum once please ?

Comment: @ Nishant Sain  I tried that , but it doesn't work